# Kernel of a map of Tate algebras

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, banach-algebras, rigid-analytic-geometry

Let $A$ and $B$ be a pair of noetherian Tate algebras over $\mathbb{Q}_p$, and assume $\text{dim}_{\text{Krull}}(B) > \text{dim}_{\text{Krull}}(A)$. Is it true that any morphism $B \longrightarrow A$ must have a non-trivial kernel?

EDIT: I care about the case where the Tate algebras are noetherian.

Answer (score 1):

No. Take $U \subset X$ a connected rational domain in a two dimensional affinoid ball, and take $C \subset U$ a Zariski closed affinoid curve which is Zariski dense in $X$. Then $\mathcal{O}(X) \to \mathcal{O}(C)$ is injective.

Comment: I understand that you are alluding to some type of a "plane filling curve". Could you please elaborate a bit more? I am not sure I understand how this works. Is it possible to take $X = \text{Spm}(\mathbb{Q}_p<x,y>)$ in your example, and $C$ to correspond to some noetherian localization of a 2-dimensional quotient of the Tate algebra $\mathbb{Q}_p<x_1,x_2,...,x_k>$?

Thanks in advance.